# Webpack not splitting React Router 4 Routes

Tags: reactjs, webpack-2, react-router-v4

I'm going crazy here - I can't seem to get code splitting for my routes to work: Here's my config/code (only the relevant parts)

Not sure if it has something to do with my babel configuration. Thats where all of my transpiling is happening.

I'm using React Router 4 and Webpack 2

.babelrc:

```
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "transform-decorators-legacy",
        "transform-regenerator",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "syntax-dynamic-import",
        "dynamic-import-node-sync",
        "system-import-transformer",
        ["import-inspector", {
          "serverSideRequirePath": true,
          "webpackRequireWeakId": true
        }]
      ],
      "presets": ["latest", "stage-2", "react"]
    }.......
```

webpack

```
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/Client/browser-client.js'],
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(projectPath, 'dist', 'public', 'js'),
      filename: 'client[name].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name]chunk.js',
    },
    ...
    plugins: [
      new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      children: true,
      async: true,
      minChunks: ({ resource }) => /node_modules/.test(resource),
    }),
    ]......
    module: {
      rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      ......
```

Component

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import Loadable from 'react-loadable';

const HelloWorld = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./../../Containers/HelloWorld'),
  loading: () => (<div>Loading</div>)
});

const Help = Loadable({
  loader: () => import('./../../Containers/Help'),
  loading: () => (<div>Loading</div>)
});


export default class routes extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/client/hello" component={HelloWorld}/>
        <Route exact path="/client/help" component={Help}/>
      </div>
    );
  } 
}
```

Output

```
             Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
    client.main.js     322 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
client.main.js.map  111 bytes       0  [emitted]         main
```

Any help/hint appreciated!!!!! :/

Comment: Have you tried removing `dynamic-import-node-sync` and `syntax-dynamic-import`? Or only remove `dynamic-import-node-sync`?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't solve the issue :/ I removed dynamic-import-node-sync first; then also syntax-dynamic-import from my babelrc.

Comment: Can you try once by removing the CommonChunks plugin ? i have a doubt if that is causing the issue.